# Prove there exists $v$ such that $f^3(v) = f(f(f(v))) \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ and $f: V \to V$. If $\dim Im f \geq 2n/3$, then prove there exists $v$ such that $f^3(v) = f(f(f(v))) \neq 0$

The only thing I can deduce is that $\dim \ker f \leq n/3$.

Comment: Is $f$ a linear operator?

Comment: @AlexR. yes it is a linear operator

Comment: The statement as it stands is false. Consider an $f$ represented by a $3\times3$ nilpotent Jordan block for instance. To correct the statement, change $\ge$ to $\gt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$dimImf =dim(Kerf_{\mid Im f}+dim(Im f^2)$ since $dim(Ker f)<n/3$ and $dim(Imf)\geq {{2n}\over 3}$, we deduce that $dim(Imf^2)>n/3$,

$dimImf^2=dim(Ker f_{\mid Imf^2}+dim(Imf^3)$ since $dim(Ker f)<n/3$ and $dim(Imf^2)>n/3$, we deduce that $dimImf^3>0$

Comment: How do we see the first line? $\dim Im f = \dim \ker f + \dim Im f$? And why do you have strict inequality?

Comment: Restrict $f$ to $Imf$, it is a map $f_{Im(f)}:Im(f)\rightarrow Imf^2$. and you have $=dim(Imf)=dim(Ker(f_{\mid Im f})+dimImf^2$.

Comment: Is there a reason why the inequality is strict on the kernel?

Comment: $ker(f_{\mid Im f})\subset Ker f$

Comment: Oh okay so you meant to write the strict inequality restricted to the image?

Comment: what is left out recording the kernel ?

Comment: but we have an upper bound of it, $dimE=dim Ker f+dim Imf$ implies that $dim Kerf=dim E-dim Imf<n-{{2n}\over 3}={n\over 3}$.